# Power adapter blocking adjacent plugs

Tags: electrical

Wall warts / power bricks seem to be pretty poorly designed. They always seem to block a power socket either side when used on 8-plug extensions.

What's your solution to stop them blocking adjacent plugs?

Answer (score 2):

Some wall-warts are made to plug in horizontally to avoid that problem. But then some power strips are arranged horizontally also, so it is blocked one way or the other. The better wall-warts are made to extend OUT from the plug rather than below or to the side of the plug. That way they don't interfere with adjacent plugs, but then they are too long to plug into the wall behind a piece of furniture, etc.  There is no universal solution to this problem.

Except maybe the really short (1 ft/ 30cm) "extension cords". They are made speciically to solve the problem that you present.  Here is one example of many available...

[image: 1 foot extension cord]
http://www.allelectronics.com/item/ext-11/1-ft-extension-cord/1.html

Comment: Do you know if these come in a U.K.-3 square pin format?

Comment: Would something like this work. https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Extension-Cords/Eagle-Gang-Lead-Fitted-Plug-Hanging-White/B000KHDWJE/ref=sr_1_20?ie=UTF8&qid=1483135171&sr=8-20&keywords=plug+extension And I was always under the impression that you shouldn't plug something like an extension cord into another extension cord / power strip. As there's a risk of overloading the circuit and causing a fire risk?

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution to the bulky wall wart problem is to use a cord assembly such as this:

[image]

You can find these at online retailers by searching for "AC Power Cord Y-Splitter". They are typically about 1.5 feet (0.45 meters) in length.

It may be possible to find something similar with a European or UK style plugs but it would be rather bulky. For those applications it would probably work out better to use a plug strip like this to expand your existing outlet. The one shown (check Amazon) should be able to handle at least two wall warts.

[image]